# Wait for a Publisher to complete and use it for another Publisher which returns the required data to webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a simple code, that saves some data in the database and returns the saved values

```
public Flux<Person> savePersons(Flux<Person> persons){
        Mono<Integer> lastPersonId = getLastPersonId();
        AtomicInteger idNum = new AtomicInteger();

        lastPersonId.log().subscribe(idNum::set);
        System.out.println("id num "+idNum.get()); //Obviously zero since the data is not available yet from lastPersonId Mono

        Flux<Person> personsWithId = persons.map(person->{
            person.setId(idNum.getAndIncrement());
            return person;
        });

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //Ignore the Sql Injection, was left as such for brevity.
        personsWithId.subscribe(person-> builder.append("insert into person VALUES("+person.getId()+",\""+person.getName()+"\""));

        return dbClient.execute(builder.toString()).fetch().rowsUpdated();//This fails as well, the builder has insert statements albeit with null Ids. since Id is not set yet. 
    }
```

Before saving the data I am trying to retrieve the last id number and use it for the insert statements.
How do I ensure these `Publisher` are chained.

P.S:  I understand the risk of SQL Injection. I send these query formation to an external utility to sanitize the input. I have ommited that piece of the code for brevity. I am not using batching because, mssql-r2dbc does not seem to support batching.

Update: This question is more of a newbie question in terms of someone switching from Imperatve coding and should be ignored.
With the help of some comments, answer here in SO and after writing few codes, I have written something I could understand.

```
public Mono<Integer> savePersons(Flux<Person> persons){
    AtomicInteger idNum = new AtomicInteger();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    return getLastPersonId() //returns a Mono<Integer>
            .map(AtomicInteger::new)
            .flatMapMany(val->assignIds(val, persons))
            .map(person->Sqllib.escapedSql(builder, person))
            .last()
            .map(val->dbClient.execute(builder.toString()))
            .fetch()
            .rowsUpdated();

}

private Flux<Person> assignIds(AtomicInteger val, Flux<Person> persons) {
    return persons.map(person-> {
      person.setId(val.getAndIncrement());
      return person;
    });
}
```

Comment: you can ZIP the operation of  ```Flux<Person> persons``` &  ```Mono<Integer> lastPersonId```

Comment: @AdityaRewari How do you think ZIP would be of any use in this situation?

Comment: Why are you writing your own sql?

Comment: @123 Because the r2dbc client I use does not support batching inherently.

Comment: why are you subscribing in your own application. Whomever initiated the call is the subscriber, your application is a producer, the client subscribes unless your application is the one initiating the call and you have no client.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf 
I am subscribing because I want to use the value. There are multiple publishers and I would like to chain them such that the next happens after the first one by using the value of first one.

Comment: and for that you use functions like `map`, `flatmap`,  `zip` etc. the subscriber is the calling client your application is the publisher and you should chain publishers all the way, you should read up on reactive programming basics https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html as soon as you subscribe you loose all the benefits with reactive programming and you will probably have even worse application prestanda than if you would use regular imperative programming.

Comment: also you should not build queries with strings, thats can lead to sql injections... here is a sample application using r2dbc, the `ReactiveCrudRepository` and the `@Query` annotation to parameterise a sql query , there you can build your batch query https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/r2dbc/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/r2dbc/basics/CustomerRepository.java

Comment: @ThomasAndolf
Thanks for your recommendation. Will go through the docs... Regarding sql injection, am aware of it, was left as such for brevity. However, batching does not seem to work for mssql r2dbc. It fails with exception. Checked with them in gitter and I was directed towards manually constructing the query. Btaching works with H2 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you honestly don't care about SQL injection or letting the database handle PK incrementation, you could do

```
    String query = "insert into person VALUES (%d,'%s');";
    AtomicInteger idNum = new AtomicInteger();

    return  people
            //for every flux element, join on the result of lastPersonId()
            .join(lastPersonId(),s-> Flux.never(),s-> Flux.never(), Tuples::of)
            //Create your query
            .map(t -> 
                String.format(query,t.getT2() + idNum.incrementAndGet(),
                t.getT1().getName()))
            //Merge it together
            .reduce(String::concat)
            //Create execution spec
            .map(client::execute)
            //Execute spec
            .map(DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec::fetch)
            //Get the number of updated rows
            .flatMap(UpdatedRowsFetchSpec::rowsUpdated);
```

Comment: Though not exactly a working solution, but got me in the right direction.
Also, the comments from @Thomas helped.

If batching is a problem what are my options other than writing my own sql.

Comment: @Andrews What doesn't work?  Not sure of the best solution, I know bind markers don't work over multiple statements (in Postgres at least). I don't use MSSQL,  but If you can do it non reactive connectors, then I'd take a look at how it's implemented there.